# Making an half-disappeared element in CSS visible

Tags: php, css, margin

I've been trying many techniques.. but none helped.
I tried "margin-bottom: 1em", "bottom: 2em", etc. but the element stays nearly invisible.

See the bottom of the page.. there is a sentence, which is used to be shown..

Here's the URI: http://Sulayman.org/

Can anyone help me? - Thanks!

Comment: Please include existing HTML/CSS. (Not all of it, just the relevant bits.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, increase the margin on the h1. You'll probably want to remove your inline styles and move them into classes and ID's.

```
<h1 style="font-size: 2.3em; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 0.5em;" class="title">
```

into

```
<h1 style="font-size: 2.3em; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 2.5em;" class="title">
```

Answer (score 2):

"The Pixel Developer" is correct; you need to change the value of `margin-bottom` to `2.5em` to move the footer farther down. I'm not sure why you are using inline styles instead of putting them in your stylesheet, but that is irrelevant to the problem. I changed your code in my browser and it works as you requested.

Comment: Hi Timothy--generally, this would go as a comment under the answer you're commenting on.

Comment: @DN, generally, yes. But given that Timothy's only just joined, and yet to hit the leaving-comments rep-cap (50, I think?) he can't leave comments yet, except to his own answers or to any answers to his own questions. Still, a good etiquette pointer =)

Comment: Yes, I spent a while looking for a comment button as I too felt it would be better, but then determined that perhaps I had to gain more reputation before it would let me do that. Thanks though!